# Caractere invalido no R

Tags: r, bat

Eu transformo o caractere [�] em uma letra A, dentro de um data.frame em R. Funciona perfeitamente, porém, quando criei um ".bat" para rodar esse algoritmo automaticamente pelas tarefas do windows ele apresenta o seguinte erro no arquivo de log do R out:

```
API$tabela<- str_replace_all(API$tabela, "[
API$tabela<- str_replace_all(API$tabela, "[?]"
Execution halted
```

Abaixo segue o meu ".bat":

```
ECHO ********************************************************************
REM ECHO com diretorio selecionado iniciamos  o script
ECHO ********************************************************************

"E:\Softwares\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --encoding=UTF-8 E:\arquivo.R

ECHO **************************************************
REM ECHO pausar e verificar o estado final
ECHO concluida
ECHO **************************************************
pause
```